# Syntax error when using CASE WHEN

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to add a case in the `where` part of the `select` statement in SQL Server 2008.

```
SELECT * 
FROM CR_LOAN_DTL 
WHERE 
    LOAN_ID = 1
    AND REFERENCE_NO = CASE 
                          WHEN @i_loan_id = 0 THEN >=1 
                          CASE WHEN  @i_loan_id = 0 THEN REFERENCE_NO  >=1 and REFERENCE_NO  <=9999999999999 
                               ELSE  REFERENCE_NO = @i_loan_id 
                          END
```

It's giving me an error:

> *Incorrect syntax near ">"*

How can I fix this?

Comment: **PLEASE DON'T SHOUT AT US!!** It's **rude** and unwelcome .....

Comment: I think you really need to read up on `CASE WHEN` and its syntax. I can't quite tell *what* you're trying to do, but you're missing identifiers and using conditionals where you shouldn't be...

Comment: [Read the MSDN documentation on `CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) - `CASE` in T-SQL can only return **atomic values** - not code blocks / expressions like you're trying to do ...

Answer (score 2):

Your `CASE` statement cannot return the "logic" of `>=1`. It needs to return a value, not a logical statement that needs to be parsed.

An option could be to do the following:

```
WHERE LOAN_ID=1 AND   
   ((@i_loan_id <> 0 AND REFERENCE_NO = @i_loan_id)
OR (@i_loan_id = 0 AND REFERENCE_NO BETWEEN 1 AND 9999999999999))
```